# How does the List monad work in this example?

Tags: list, haskell, monads, do-notation

The List monad has `return x = [x]`. So why in the following example is the result not `[(["a", "b"], [2, 3])]`?

```
> pairs a b = do { x <- a; y <- b; return (x, y)}
> pairs ["a", "b"] [2,3]
[("a",2),("a",3),("b",2),("b",3)]
```

Comment: because - the list monad also has a `(>>=) = concatMap` bind operation which you use implicitly with `(<-)`. It is best you try to de-sugar the do notation yourself and see how far you get. The gist is that you in each `x <- a` you bind each *element* of the monad and not the whole list.

Comment: Do you understand how bind works?

Comment: Because the `return` has as argument `(x, y)`, so it produces `[(x,y)]`.

Comment: `pairs = return` would provide your expected value. `<-` is *not* just assignment; it's more of an *extraction* operator.

Comment: @chepner (you meant `pairs = curry return`.)

Comment: Because `do` notation doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't just run things in order.

Comment: @WillNess Apparently :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us first analyze and rewrite the function `pairs`:

```
pairs a b = do { x <- a; y <- b; return (x, y)}
```

Here we thus have a monad. We use `do` as syntactical sugar. But the compiler rewrites this to:

```
pairs a b = a >>= (\x -> b >>= (\y -> return (x, y)))
```

Or in a more canonical form:

```
pairs a b = (>>=) a (\x -> (>>=) b (\y -> return (x, y)))
```

Now the list monad is defined as:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    (>>=) xs f = concatMap f xs
```

So we have written:

```
pairs a b = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> [(x, y)]) b) a
```

So we thus take as input two lists `a` and `b`, and we perform a `concatMap` on `a` with as function `(\x -> concatMap (\y -> [(x, y)]) b)`. In that function we perform another `concatMap` on `b` with as function `\y -> [(x, y)]`.

So if we evaluate this with `pairs ["a", "b"] [2,3]` we get:

```
   pairs ["a", "b"] [2,3]
-> concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> [(x, y)]) [2,3]) ["a", "b"]
-> concatMap (\y -> [("a", y)]) [2,3] ++ concatMap (\y -> [("b", y)]) [2,3]
-> [("a", 2)] ++ [("a", 3)] ++ [("b", 2)] ++ [("b", 3)]
-> [("a", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 2), ("b", 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out. My confusion was that <- is not just an assignment, and in fact for the List monad involves mapping over following operations. I think your answer would be improved greatly by skipping over concatMap and using concat and map directly, as that's an extra level of abstraction someone struggling with this will have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

In general,

```
pairs a b = do { x <- a; y <- b; return (x, y) }  
          = do { x <- a;
                    do { y <- b; 
                            do { return (x, y) }}}
```

means, in pseudocode,

```
pairs( a, b) {  for x in a do: 
                     for y in b do: 
                                 yield( (x, y) ); 
             }
```

whatever the `"for ... in ... do"` and `"yield"` mean for the particular monad. More formally, it's

```
          = a  >>= (\x ->
                    do { y <- b;                          -- a >>= k  ===
                            do { return (x, y) }})        -- join (k <$> a)
          = join ( (<$> a)                                --  ( a       :: m a
                   (\x ->                                 --    k       ::   a ->   m b
                    do { y <- b;                          --    k <$> a :: m       (m b) )
                            do { return (x, y) }}) )      --            :: m          b
```

( `(<$>)` is an alias for `fmap`).

For the `Identity` monad, where `return a = Identity a` and `join (Identity (Identity a)) = Identity a`, it is indeed

```
pairs( {Identity, a}, {Identity, b}) {  x = a; 
                                        y = b; 
                                        yield( {Identity, {Pair, x, y}} ); 
                                     }
```

For the list monad though, `"for"` means `foreach`, because `return x = [x]` and  `join xs = concat xs`:

```
-- join :: m (m a) -> m a
-- join :: [] ([] a) -> [] a
-- join :: [[a]] -> [a]
join = concat
```

and so,

```
join    [ [a1, a2, a3, ...],
          [b1, b2, b3, ...],
           .....
          [z1, z2, z3, ...] ]
=
        [  a1, a2, a3, ... ,
           b1, b2, b3, ... ,
            .....
           z1, z2, z3, ...  ]
```

Monadic bind satisfies `ma >>= k  =  join (fmap k ma)` where `ma :: m a, k :: a -> m b` for a `Monad m`. Thus for lists, where `fmap = map`, we have `ma >>= k  =  join (fmap k ma) = concat (map k ma) = concatMap k ma`:

```
m >>= k  =  [ a,        = join [ k a,   = join [ [ a1, a2, ... ],  =  [  a1, a2, ... ,
              b,                 k b,            [ b1, b2, ... ],        b1, b2, ... ,
              c,                 k c,            [ c1, c2, ... ],        c1, c2, ... ,
              d,                 k d,            [ d1, d2, ... ],        d1, d2, ... ,
              e,                 k e,            [ e1, e2, ... ],        e1, e2, ... ,
             ... ] >>= k         ...  ]          ...............  ]      ...........   ]
```

which is exactly what *nested loops* do. Thus

```
pairs ["a",                                   -- for x in ["a", "b"] do:
       "b"] [2, 3]                            --          for y in [2, 3] do:
=                                             --                     yield (x,y)
      ["a", 
       "b"] >>= (\x-> join (fmap (\y -> return (x,y)) [2, 3]) )
=
      ["a", 
       "b"] >>= (\x-> concat (map (\y -> [ (x,y) ]) [2, 3]) )
=
join [ "a"  &   (\x-> concat ((\y -> [ (x,y) ]) `map` [2, 3]) ),      -- x & f = f x
       "b"  &   (\x-> concat ((\y -> [ (x,y) ]) `map` [2, 3]) ) ]     
=
join [              concat ((\y -> [ ("a",y) ]) `map` [2, 3])  ,    
                    concat ((\y -> [ ("b",y) ]) `map` [2, 3])   ]     
=
join [ concat [ [("a", 2)], [("a", 3)] ] ,    -- for y in [2, 3] do: yield ("a",y)
       concat [ [("b", 2)], [("b", 3)] ] ]    -- for y in [2, 3] do: yield ("b",y)
=
join [        [  ("a", 2) ,  ("a", 3)  ] ,
              [  ("b", 2) ,  ("b", 3)  ] ]
=
     [           ("a", 2) ,  ("a", 3)    ,
                 ("b", 2) ,  ("b", 3)    ]
```

Loop unrolling is what nested loops do ⁄ *are*, and *nested computations* are the essence of Monad.

It is also interesting to notice that

```
 join                =                      =   [a1] ++            =  [a1] ++ join
  [ [ a1, a2, ... ],    [ a1, a2, ... ] ++          [a2, ... ] ++         [ [a2, ...],
    [ b1, b2, ... ],    [ b1, b2, ... ] ++     [ b1, b2, ... ] ++      [ b1, b2, ...],
    [ c1, c2, ... ],    [ c1, c2, ... ] ++     [ c1, c2, ... ] ++      [ c1, c2, ...],
    [ d1, d2, ... ],    [ d1, d2, ... ] ++     [ d1, d2, ... ] ++      [ d1, d2, ...],
    [ e1, e2, ... ],    [ e1, e2, ... ] ++     [ e1, e2, ... ] ++      [ e1, e2, ...],
    ............... ]   ...............        ...............         ..............  ]
```

which goes to the heart of the "nested loops ⁄ yield" analogy. Monads are higher order monoids, *"what's the problem?"*