# Haskell, list comprehension outputs empty list. Why?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, evaluation

`[x:ys | x<-[1,2], ys<-[]]`

above code outputs `[]`. I thought it should output `[1,2]`.

So what am I get wrong with Haskell evaluation?

Comment: Imagine that the two arrows represent nested for loops; the outer one over `xs`, the inner one over `ys`. The thing to the left of the pipe is the loop body.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl, can you move your comment to answer section?

Comment: If you're just trying to concatenate two lists, you can do `[1, 2] ++ []`, which yields the expected `[1, 2]`.

Comment: `{ for each x in [1,2]: { for each ys in []: yield (x:ys) } }` == `{ { for each ys in []: yield (1:ys)} ; { for each ys in []: yield (2:ys)} }` == `{ for none: yield ... } ; { for none: yield ... } }` == `{none ; none }` == `none`.

Comment: ys in the result is not a list. Try ys<-[[]] ] to produce a list in x:ys -- it will yield x, that is x:[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions express nested loops:

```
[x:ys | x<-[1,2], ys<-[]]
 ==
do { x<-[1,2] ; do { ys<-[] ; return (x:ys) } }
 ==
{ for each x in [1,2]: { for each ys in []: yield (x:ys) } }
 == 
{ { for each ys in []: yield (1:ys) }     
; { for each ys in []: yield (2:ys) }     
}
 == 
{ { for none: yield ... } ; { for none: yield ... } }
 == 
{ none ; none }
 == 
none.
```

This is reminiscent of matrix multiplication:

```
join [ {- for 1: -}  [ a,b,c   ],       [  1a, 1b, 1c,
       {- for 2: -}  [ d,e     ],   =      2d, 2e,
       {- for 3: -}  [ f,g,h,i ],          3f, 3g, 3h, 3i
        ]                                                 ]
```

Thus if the list produced for each element of the first list is empty, the total list is empty as well, because `concat [ [], [], [] ] == []`.

See also: [How does the List monad work in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960899/how-does-the-list-monad-work-in-this-example/49030523#49030523)

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your expectation:

1. `x:ys` always creates a new list; `x:[] == [x]`, not `x:[] == x`.
2. Even if `x:[] == x`, the fact remains that `ys <- []` does not assign the name `ys` to the empty list; it assigns `ys` to a value *contained* in the empty list (and of course, there is no such value to assign to `ys`).

You could change `ys <- []` to `ys <- [[]]`, in which case you would get

```
> [x:ys | x<-[1,2], ys<-[[]]]
[[1], [2]]
```

but if you want `[1,2]`, the trivial list comprehension would simply be

```
> [x | x <- [1,2]]
[1,2]
```

with no other list involved, because you don't want a list of lists as your answer.