# How to implement a function using bind (>>=)

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I wrote a filter function:

```
f :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
f p xs = case xs of
         [] -> []
         x : xs' -> if p x
                    then x : f p xs'
                    else f p xs'
```

To understand bind, I want to implement this using bind.
What I was thinking about:

```
f p xs = xs >>= (\x xs -> if p x then x : f p xs else f p xs)
```

But I get this error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `[a] -> [a]'
    * The lambda expression `\ x xs -> ...' has two arguments,
      but its type `a -> [a]' has only one
      In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely
        `(\ x xs -> if p x then x : f p xs else f p xs)'
      In the expression:
        xs >>= (\ x xs -> if p x then x : f p xs else f p xs)
    * Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:104:5)
        p :: a -> Bool (bound at <interactive>:104:3)
        f :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] (bound at <interactive>:104:1)
```

Successfully did it using `foldr`:

```
f p xs = foldr (\x xs -> if p x then x : f p xs else f p xs) [] xs
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: This is not a `do` block, so no binds are used here.

Comment: List bind `>>=` is `concatMap`, not `foldr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To understand bind, i want to implement this as bind.

There is no bind here. The bind is added in case of a [*`do` expression*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14). The above is not a do-expression, so there is no bind here.

You can however write this with bind, like:

```
f p xs = xs >>= \x -> if p x then [x] else []
```

but this is not a literal mapping of the original function, we simply make use of the `instance Monad []` implementation here. Nevertheless, your `f` is just [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) here.

Answer (score 2):

To understand bind, first implement the *no-op*:

```
id_list xs   =  concat [ [x]       | x <- xs ]  =  [ y | x <- xs, y <- [x      ] ]
```

Now for the *filter*, augment it as

```
filter p xs  =  concat [ [x | p x] | x <- xs ]  =  [ y | x <- xs, y <- [x | p x] ]
```

How is this code using bind, you ask? If we're using `MonadComprehensions`, it does.

The explicit `do`-notation re-write is straightforward:

```
id_list xs   =  do { x <- xs ; y <- [ x      ] ; return y }
filter p xs  =  do { x <- xs ; y <- [ x | p x] ; return y }
```

And of course, for lists,

```
[x]       ==  return x
[x | p x] ==  if p x then return x else mzero
mzero     ==  []
concat    ==  join
```

This brings us back to an explicitly recursive way to code `filter` as

```
filter p []     =  []
filter p (x:xs) =  [x | p x] ++ filter p xs
```

With bind, we think in terms of transforming *each* element of the list *individually,* into *the list of results* (none, one, or several) for that one input element. Your `foldr`-based code breaks this.

---

So, the code itself is just

```
filter_bind p xs  =  xs  >>=  (\x -> [x | p x])
```

because we have

```
xs >>= f  ==  join (fmap f xs) 
          ==  concat (map f xs) 
          ==  concat [ f x | x <- xs ]
          ==  foldr (++) []
                     [ f x | x <- xs ]
```

with the last snippet corresponding to the explicitly recursive definition above.

See also

- [How does the List monad work in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960899/how-does-the-list-monad-work-in-this-example/49030523#49030523)
- [Haskell Monad - How does Monad on list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172904/haskell-monad-how-does-monad-on-list-work/51178620#51178620)
- [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891%20list%20monad)